# Долго грузится сайт

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Залил сайт на хостинг, очень долго грузятся страницы, иногда вылетает ошибка 500.
Вот ссылка на сайт: [ссылка](http://webcode.esy.es/)

Проблема в коде или в сервере?

Comment: Без внутреннего профилирования не сказать. Попробуйте для начала замерить время работы PHP, если оно сильно отличается от времени загрузки, то проблема в сервере.

Comment: По любой причине. так угадать невозможно. Но в коде точно есть ошибки, при нажатии на первую же попавшуюся ссылку появилась куча чисто php ошибок связанных с неправильной передачей параметров

Comment: @Mike если вы про `chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED` Это не с `php` связано, это связано с тем, что видео из ютуб грузят во фрейм. это сам ютуб некорректно себя ведет.... кстати можно посмотреть что будет если видео это отключить как раз

Comment: неплохо было бы лог ошибок в вопросе привести

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, я про `in BlogController.php line 108
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'Missing argument 3 for App\Http\Controllers\BlogController::show()', '/home/u176062291/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/BlogController.php', '108', array('auth' => object(Guard), 'category' => 'post-875')) in BlogController.php line 108`

Comment: У меня довольно быстро грузится, но тут я хз, то ли я просто удачно попал, то ли из - за того что у меня гигабитный интернет. Но ошибок действительно много. Сделайте тесты, для начала просто нагрузочный тест, можно заюзать JMeter, перед этим настройте логи тяжелых запросов, и включить все логи... Я полагаю ИМХО что проблема с хостом ибо иногда дешевые хостеры экономят и размещают на сервере который может нормально держать только 50 сайтов 100...Вообщем тут только тестить и првить

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, что заметили ошибку, все исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Профилируйте свой сайт для получения детальной информации о том, какие процессы работают медленно.

Рекомендую в качестве профайлера использовать:

http://xhprof.io/

или онлайн сервис

http://newrelic.com

Недорогой хостинг с SSD накопителем:
[DigitalOcean](https://m.do.co/c/78259d4099e4)

При регистрации на DigitalOcean $10 от хостера в подарок (реферал)

Answer (score 1):

[Сервис анализирующий скорость сайта](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebcode.esy.es%2F).
Загрузите сжатые изображения и css-файлы (их можно скачать на вкладке "для компьютеров" этого сервиса).
Добавьте следующие строчки в .htaccess для сжатия и кеширования сайта, что ускорит быстродействие

**Сжатие:**

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

**Кеширование:**

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас достаточно тяжелый фронт-энд. Но основная проблема не в нем.
Ответ на **GET /** приходит только через **12 секунд**.... (иногда не приходит).

У вас или очень слабый сервер или очень плохой бэк-энд.
Или очень большая нагрузка. (что сомнительно)